# jQuery: Nested Sortable Items work fine in good browsers, but in IE7, both the sortable child, and the parent drag at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

Here is my code for you all to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/SMqR9/1/ =D

works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari, Good Browsers, etc.

But when in IE7, when I click on "New Content" and drag, it moves the section it's in also (and at different speeds). Really weird behavior. Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see here for a working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/SMqR9/16/

Most important part is this:

```
    $j('ul').bind('mousedown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Which stops IE7 from having nested sortable elements bubble up the mousedown-event to their parent items.
Make sure to use .bind(), as .live() only takes place after the event already bubbled up

Comment: that fixed the drag problem. But now when I drag up, the item is on top of everything (like it should be) but when I drag down, the dragged item goes underneath.

Comment: I will make a new question =D

Comment: I'll look into that more, there then :P I think it is related to IE weighing nesting > z-index, i remember there was a "non-standard feature" or, as regular users call it, bug :D

Comment: Here is the link for those following these comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850154/ie7-css-jquery-dragging-up-dragged-item-is-on-top-dragging-down-dragged-it